# Azure Web App Slot Kudu site domain has no dns record after creation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-deployment-slots

I couldn't find any similar cases by googling, but I have experienced it at least twice in the past a couple of days.

Our DevOps process for a Web App deletes the current slot and create a new one then do Web Deploy.

The issue is that sometime after the new slot is created; the Web Deploy task fails because there is no dns record for Kudu site domain: -.scm.azurewebsites.net.

```
  2020-03-24T15:21:06.4051574Z ##[error]Error: Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID
  More Information:  Could not connect to the remote computer ("<app-name>-<slot-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.
  Error: The remote name could not be resolved: '<app-name>-<slot-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net'
  Error count: 1.
```

When I try to ping or use global ping services for this domain -.scm.azurewebsites.net, there is no DNS records.

If we try the process again, which is delete the slot and create it again, the issue normally goes away.

Has anyone experienced this before? Thanks!

Comment: The format is correct. Are you sure there are no typos?

Comment: `The remote name could not be resolved`, this means it may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The format you have shown is correct, please check the following three points:

First, there may be a typo. Please check your spelling for problems.

Second, you may need to wait for the negative cache to expire.

Third, please avoid repeatedly deleting slots and creating new slots. After creating a new slot, a new deployment file will be generated, and userPWD will become different from last time.